# SSAS Dimension Sorting While Browsing In Excel

Tags: ssas, powerbi

I have a SSAS cube which I browse in Excel, The problem is order of dimension. I Have a dimension named accounts which has hierarchy to show list of accounts, but excel shows accounts in alphabetical order based on there name, while I want them to be displayed based on the key field that is AccountID.

Further If I share this cube in Power BI as a dataset, and let users connect this dataset through Excel, can control the order of sorting while browsing the same in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the order of attributes in the dimension?

```
AccountID AccountName
1         Credit
2         Automobile
3         Lease
```

Your current order is Automobile, Credit, Lease but you want it as depicted in the table?

If so you need to set the "order by" attribute in the individual attributes to "Key" instead of "Name", with Key being AccountID and Name being AccountName.
(In SSDT: Rightclick the dimension attribute -> Properties, the 10th entry or so)

Comment: This does not work in excel, this works with other vizualisation tools but not excel.

Comment: This also works in Excel. My date hierarchy shows the months in Jan-Feb-March for the first quarter and not Feb-Jan-March as it would be alphabetically. Or did I misunderstand your original question?

Comment: Other than order bu attribute I also had to set KeyColumn attribute for dimension attributes, after which I was able to sort this in correct order.